# SPI problem with PIC18LF27K42

Tags: pic, spi, microchip

I am facing issue using SPI with a PIC18LF27K42 in order to drive a micro SDcard.

I am not very confortable with these "new" PIC18LF27K42 and i am trying to fix this issue since several weeks without success.

Currently i can drive the micro SDcard with a PIC18LF14K50 and all functions are working fine.

And the problem is that when i am trying to initialize the SD card by sending the command GO_IDLE_STATE (CMD0) i should have a R1= 0x01 response. But get always 0x00 as response. So i cannot go further in the SD card initialization.

With the PIC18LF27K42 i am suspecting the following potential issues

- PIC initialisation
- SPI functions

Thank you for your help and guidance.

- Compiler : XC8 v1.45
- IDE      : MPLABX v5.15
- external 4MHz quartz

I am using the following pin

RA5 (pin 7)  : SPI_CS   : the Slave Select pin is controled by the software

RC2 (pin 13) : SPI_SDO

RC3 (pin 14) : SPI_SCK

RC4 (pin 15) : SPI_SDI

**PIC initialisation**

```
/* Initializing PORTA */
PORTA   = 0;
LATA    = 0;
ANSELA  = 0;
TRISA   = 0b11010000;

/* Initializing PORTB */
PORTB   = 0;
LATB    = 0;
ANSELB  = 0
TRISB   = 0b11111111;

/* Initializing PORTC */
PORTC   = 0;
LATC    = 0;
ANSELC  = 0;
TRISC   = 0b00010011;

/* map peripherals */
PPSLOCK = 0x55;
PPSLOCK = 0xAA;
PPSLOCKbits.PPSLOCKED = 0x00;

/* Peripheral Input Selection */
SPI1SDIPPS  = 0x04;

/* Peripheral Output Selection */
RC2PPS = 0b011111;    /* OUTPUT : SPI_SDO  */
RC3PPS = 0b011110;    /* OUTPUT : SPI_SCK  */

PPSLOCK = 0x55;
PPSLOCK = 0xAA;
PPSLOCKbits.PPSLOCKED = 0x01; // lock PPS
```

**SPI initialisation and functions**

```
void SPI_Init (void){
    SPI1CON0bits.EN = 0;   // disable SPI for reset and reconfiguration

    SPI1CLK     = 0x00;    // select the clock Frequency (4MHz)
    SPI1BAUD    = 0x07;    // set the SCK freq. to 250KHz with a 4MHz clock
    SPI1TWIDTH  = 0x00;    // set 8 bits width data transfert

    SPI1CON0 = 0x03;       // SPI as Master, MSB first, BMODE = 1

    SPI1CON1 = 0x00;    // SPI1 Polarity and Sampling control
    SPI1CON2 = 0x03;    // TXR = 1, RXR = 1, Slave Select disabled
    SPI1INTE = 0x00;    // disable all interrupt
    SPI1INTF = 0x00;    // clear all flags
    __delay_ms(200);
    return;
}

unsigned char SPI_Read (void){
    SPI1STATUSbits.CLRBF = 1;   // clearing the RXFIFO and TXFIFO buffers, related to
                                // SPI1RXB and SPI1TXB registers respectively
    SPI1TCNTH = 0;
    SPI1TCNTL = 1;         // One byte transfert counter
    SPI1CON0bits.EN = 1;   // enable SPI1 peripheral
    SPI1TXB = 0xFF;        // write the data into the output buffer
    while (SPI1CON2bits.BUSY); // wait until Reception is completed
   SPI1CON0bits.EN = 0;    // disable SPI1 peripheral

   return (SPI1RXB);       // return with byte read 
}


void SPI_Write (unsigned char data_out){
    SPI1STATUSbits.CLRBF = 1;   // clearing the RXFIFO and TXFIFO buffers, related to
                                // SPI1RXB and SPI1TXB registers respectively
    SPI1TCNTH = 0;
    SPI1TCNTL = 1;
    SPI1CON0bits.EN = 1;   // enable SPI1 peripheral
    SPI1TXB = data_out;    // write the data into the output buffer
    while (SPI1CON2bits.BUSY);   // wait until Transmition is complete
    SPI1CON0bits.EN = 0;   // disable SPI1 peripheral

    return;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem that you are having? Not working, doesn't give much to go on. What are the symptoms? What have you tried?

Comment: When i am trying to initialize the SD card by sending the command GO_IDLE_STATE (CMD0) i should have a R1= 0x01 response. And the problem is that i cannot have that response from the SD card, having always 0x00. So i cannot go further in the SD card initialization.

Comment: 0x00 could also be an electrical problem because if the MISO line is low all the time that would look like all zeroes. Do you have a logic analyzer to look at the lines?

Comment: Thank you to having a look at my issue. Unfortunetly i do not have a logic analyzer. But i am using the very same interface, SD card, as with the PIC18LF14K50 .

Comment: I put a 47K of pullup resistor on the MISO line (RC4 pin 15) but i am still getting 0x00 for R1 response.

Comment: PPS is not locked on POR or BOR by default. It may be messing with the pin assignments to unlock it first. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

```
unsigned char SPI_Read (void){
    SPI1STATUSbits.CLRBF = 1;   // clearing the RXFIFO and TXFIFO buffers, related to
                                // SPI1RXB and SPI1TXB registers respectively
    SPI1TCNTH = 0;
    SPI1TCNTL = 1;         // One byte transfert counter
    SPI1CON0bits.EN = 1;   // enable SPI1 peripheral
    SPI1TXB = 0xFF;        // write the data into the output buffer
    while (SPI1CON2bits.BUSY); // wait until Reception is completed
    SPI1CON0bits.EN = 0;    // disable SPI1 peripheral

    return (SPI1RXB);       // return with byte read 
}
```

Needs to change to this.

```
unsigned char SPI_Read (void){
    SPI1STATUSbits.CLRBF = 1;   // clearing the RXFIFO and TXFIFO buffers, related to
                                // SPI1RXB and SPI1TXB registers respectively
    SPI1TCNTH = 0;
    SPI1TCNTL = 1;         // One byte transfert counter
    SPI1CON0bits.EN = 1;   // enable SPI1 peripheral
    SPI1TXB = 0xFF;        // write the data into the output buffer
    while (SPI1CON2bits.BUSY); // wait until Reception is completed
    unsigned char buff = SPI1RXB; //Store the buffer value before disabling the module. 
    SPI1CON0bits.EN = 0;    // disable SPI1 peripheral

    return (buff);       // return with byte read 
}
```

When you disable the SPI module the buffers are cleared. So you have to store the buffer value before disabling the module. From the data sheet.

> Setting the CLRBF bit of
>   SPIxSTATUS resets the occupancy for both FIFOs,
>   emptying both buffers. The FIFOs are also reset by disabling the SPI module.

Comment: Waouh, ... i've read the datasheet several times but miss this point, thank you very much. This is clearly the main point but unfortunatly it seems that is other issue remains as i am still getting R1=0x00 for CMD0.
I've made the following modifications on the code.
- In SPI_Init() : i enabled the SPI module at the end of the function

Comment: - In SPI_Init : i enabled the SPI module SPI1CON0bits.EN = 1 before the the 200ms delay
- In SPI_Read and SPI_Write function i removed the  disabling SPI line (SPI1CON0bits.EN = 0)
And by doing this i am getting R1=0x80

Comment: The bit7 of the R1 response is unused and read as 0. So the SD card do not respond with 0x80.

A thought, assuming that the SD card is sending the expected 0x01, would it mean that somewhere there is a 7 bits left shift ? but well, this is just a thought.

Comment: The SPI functions are now working, thanks to vini_i.
I made few additional changes in the SPI_Init function to make it operational.
SPI1CON1 = 0x20.
SPI1CON2 = 0x07.
But i see a strange behavior that i cannot explain.
LATAbits.LATA5 related to SPI_CS_LAT remains on low level even after a LATAbits.LATA5 = 1. So the SD remains selected by the chip.